# Angular 4 combine data from multiple HTTP requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-http

I'm using angular 4 and I try to get data from 2 endpoints but I have a problem understanding rxjs.

with this code I can only get list of students and users only.

```
 getStudent() {
    return this.http.get(this.url + this.student_url, this.getHeaders()).map(res => res.json());
  }

getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.url + this.users_url, this.getHeaders()).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Let's say this is data :
Student

```
[{"ID" : 1 , "SchoolCode": "A150", "UserID": 1 }, 
{"ID" : 5 , "SchoolCode": "A140" , "UserID": 3}, 
{"ID" : 9 , "SchoolCode": "C140" , "UserID": 4}]
```

User

```
[{"ID" : 1  ,"Name": "Rick" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" },
{"ID" : 4 ,"Name": "Carle" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" }]
```

I want to get first all students then compare UserID if it's the same as user then I combine both objects into one until I get an array like this :

```
{"ID" : 1 , "SchoolCode": "A150","Name": "Rick" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" }
```

I think I should use flatmap but I did try write code but it dosen't work for me and I didn't find an example with such logic.

Could you please help me.

Comment: flatmap allows you to change streams, for example, you could ask for the students and then get the list of courses for a particular student that would be a good option; in this case you always need both lists and then you can do some logic, so you might need forkjoin, merge or combine to do so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `switchMap` operator (alias of `flatMap`) in the following code :

```
// Observables mocking the data returned by http.get()
const studentObs = Rx.Observable.from([
  {"ID" : 1 , "SchoolCode": "A150", "UserID": 1 }, 
  {"ID" : 5 , "SchoolCode": "A140" , "UserID": 4}, 
  {"ID" : 9 , "SchoolCode": "C140" , "UserID": 3}
]);
const userObs = Rx.Observable.from([
  {"ID" : 1, "Name": "Rick" , "FamilyName": "Grimes" },
  {"ID" : 3, "Name": "Tom" , "FamilyName": "Cruise" },
  {"ID" : 4, "Name": "Amy" , "FamilyName": "Poehler" }
]);
// Return an observable emitting only the given user.
function getUser(userID) {
  return userObs.filter(user => user.ID === userID);
}

studentObs
  .switchMap(student => {
     return getUser(student.UserID).map(user => {
       // Merge the student and the user.
       return Object.assign(student, {user: user});
     })
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/batuzaq/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

interface Student {
  id: number;
  schoolCode: string;
  userId: number;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  familyName: string;
}

interface Merged {
  id: number;
  schoolCode: string;
  name: string;
  familyName: string;
}

getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
    // Implementation
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    // Implementation
  }

  getMerged(): Observable<Merged[]> {
    const student$ = this.getStudents();
    const users$ = this.getUsers();
    const merged$ = forkJoin(student$, users$)
      .map(src => src[0].reduce((acc, current) => {
        // acc is the accumulated result (list with mapped objects)
        // current is an element of the students list
        const user = src[1].find(u => u.id === current.userId);
        // check if there is a user associated to the current student element
        if (user) { // if there is a matching user, push new element to result list
          acc.push({
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            familyName: user.familyName,
            schoolCode: current.schoolCode
          });
        }
        return acc;
        // this could be changed to use a more immutable based approach
      }, new Array<Merged>()));
      // the seed value to start accumulating results is an empty list
    return merged$;
  }
```